# Viewholder taking too much time to load for Listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an application where I take input such as no of users and populate some some fixes name,phone...etc in terms of a listview. I have used viewholder in order to optimize all my listviews. All the listviews work fine except for a listview where it loads userdata.

[image]

From the picture you can see that the first and last rows are loaded however the middle two rows are not loaded and do take a lot of time to load. The information I feed to every row is initially same and are left for the user to modify. Here's the code I use for that.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,final ViewGroup parent)
{
    View rowview = convertView;
    if(rowview == null)
    {
        ViewHolder viewholder = new ViewHolder();
        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_skeleton_people_expenses, parent, false);
        viewholder.tv1 = (TextView)rowview.findViewById(R.id.name);
        viewholder.tv2 = (TextView)rowview.findViewById(R.id.destination);
        viewholder.tv3 = (TextView)rowview.findViewById(R.id.start);
        viewholder.tv4 = (TextView)rowview.findViewById(R.id.phno);
        viewholder.rowview = rowview;
        rowview.setTag(viewholder);
    }
    else
    {   
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowview.getTag();
        UserData temp = objects.get(position);
        holder.tv1.setText(temp.name);

        holder.tv2.setText("Destination: "+temp.loc);

        holder.tv3.setText("Start: "+start);

        String phone_txt = objects.get(position).phno;
        phone_txt = "("+phone_txt.substring(0, 3)+") "+phone_txt.substring(3, 6)+"-"+phone_txt.substring(6, 10);

        holder.tv4.setText(phone_txt);
    }
    return rowview;
}

static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4;
    View rowview;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to populate your text views outside of the if else statement. The ones in the middle are being caught by the first case and the properties are not filled.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,final ViewGroup parent)
{
    View rowview = convertView; 
    ViewHolder viewholder;

    if (rowview == null) {
        viewholder = new ViewHolder();
        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_skeleton_people_expenses, parent, false);
        viewholder.tv1 = (TextView)rowview.findViewById(R.id.name);
        viewholder.tv2 = (TextView)rowview.findViewById(R.id.destination);
        viewholder.tv3 = (TextView)rowview.findViewById(R.id.start);
        viewholder.tv4 = (TextView)rowview.findViewById(R.id.phno);
        viewholder.rowview = rowview;
        rowview.setTag(viewholder);     
    } else {
        viewholder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    UserData temp = objects.get(position);

    holder.tv1.setText(temp.name);

    holder.tv2.setText("Destination: "+temp.loc);

    holder.tv3.setText("Start: "+start);

    String phone_txt = objects.get(position).phno;
    phone_txt = "("+phone_txt.substring(0, 3)+") "+phone_txt.substring(3, 6)+"-"+phone_txt.substring(6, 10);

    holder.tv4.setText(phone_txt);
    return rowview;
}
```

Also, random bit of advice, try to use a StringBuilder instead of Concatenating a bunch of strings together with the '+' operator as its pretty inefficient. Each time you use the '+' Java creates a new StringBuilder object in the background to append the strings together because strings are not mutable. So might as well just create one StringBuilder and append to it the strings you want to concatenate instead of using '+' four or five times and forcing it to create more unnecessary objects that the garbage collector will have to clean up.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Oops...looked at the code many times but haven't realized that simple mistake. Thanks for the code and the advice too.